# Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules in Vuejs3

Tags: api, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3, ckeditor5

I'm trying to install ckeditor. In console getting this error[image] Here is my package.json file[image]. In ckeditor5 module getting same error when I import font plugin.Now I'm trying to install all plugins manually.

```
<template>
<div id="app">
    <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
</div>
```

```
<script>
// ⚠️ NOTE: We don't use @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic any more!
// Since we're building CKEditor from source, we use the source version of ClassicEditor.
// import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';

import EssentialsPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import BoldPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import ItalicPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';
import LinkPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link';
import ParagraphPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';

export default {
    name: 'app',
    data() {
        return {
            editor: ClassicEditor,
            editorData: '<p>Content of the editor.</p>',
            editorConfig: {
                plugins: [
                    EssentialsPlugin,
                    BoldPlugin,
                    ItalicPlugin,
                    LinkPlugin,
                    ParagraphPlugin
                ],

                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'bold',
                        'italic',
                        'link',
                        'undo',
                        'redo'
                    ]
                }
            }
        };
    }
};
```